# Sitecore with Docker and TDS

Tags: docker

I am running Sitecore with docker containers and all services are up and running via docker-compose. This project uses TDS. Now I need to expose the CM's website root folder from the running container to my host, so I can configure the TDS projects in VS. But many files are not created when I add the following volume to CM service making CM to stop working.
- .\cmwebsite:C:\Sitecore\website

CM docker file:

```
# escape=`
ARG BASE_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803

FROM $BASE_IMAGE

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

COPY .\*.zip .

RUN Expand-Archive -Path 'C:\Sitecore*.zip' -DestinationPath 'C:'; `
    Remove-Item 'C:\Sitecore*.zip' -Force; `
    New-Item -Path 'C:\Sitecore' -Type Directory | Out-Null; `
    Move-Item -Path 'C:\Sitecore *\Data' -Destination 'C:\Sitecore'; `
    Move-Item -Path 'C:\Sitecore *\Website' -Destination 'C:\Sitecore'; `
    Remove-Item -Path 'C:\Sitecore\Data\logs' -Recurse -Force; `
    Remove-Item -Path 'C:\Sitecore *rev*' -Recurse -Force;

COPY Sitecore /Sitecore
COPY license.xml /Sitecore/Data

RUN Import-Module WebAdministration; `
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -Name 'physicalPath' -Value 'C:\Sitecore\Website'; `
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool' -Name 'enable32BitAppOnWin64' -Value 'True'; `
    Set-Itemproperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters' -Name ServerPriorityTimeLimit -Value 0 -Type DWord; `
    setx /M PATH $($env:PATH + ';C:\Sitecore\Scripts');
```

And here is docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.4'

services:

  sql:
    image: sitecore-sqldev
    volumes:
      - .\sovereign\sitecore-sqldev\dbs:C:\Data
    mem_limit: 2GB
    ports:
      - "44010:1433"

  solr:
    image: solr:4.10
    ports: 
      - "8990:8983"

  cm:
    image: sitecore-cm:8.1.160519-windowsservercore-1803
    volumes:
      - .\cmwebsite:C:\Sitecore\website
      -  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger:C:\remote_debugger:ro
      - .\data\cm:C:\Sitecore\Data\logs
      - .\src:c:\inetpub\wwwroot
    ports:
      - "44001:80"
    links:
      - sql
      - solr
    entrypoint: cmd /c "start /B powershell C:/sitecore/scripts/Watch-Directory.ps1 C:/inetpub/wwwroot C:\Sitecore\website & C:\\remote_debugger\\x64\\msvsmon.exe /noauth /anyuser /silent /nostatus /noclrwarn /nosecuritywarn /nofirewallwarn /nowowwarn /timeout:2147483646"

  cd:
    image: sitecore-cd:8.1.160519-windowsservercore-1803
    volumes:
      -  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger:C:\remote_debugger:ro
      - .\data\cd:C:\Sitecore\Data\logs
      - .\src:c:\inetpub\wwwroot
    ports:
      - "44002:80"
    links:
      - sql
      - solr
    entrypoint: cmd /c "start /B powershell C:/sitecore/scripts/Watch-Directory.ps1 C:/inetpub/wwwroot C:\Sitecore\website & C:\\remote_debugger\\x64\\msvsmon.exe /noauth /anyuser /silent /nostatus /noclrwarn /nosecuritywarn /nofirewallwarn /nowowwarn /timeout:2147483646"
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot mount a volume to an existing directory inside your container on *Windows Docker*. You need to map up a new directory and then use some means of moving the files to the destination you ultimately want.

This is what `Watch-Directory` takes care of in your `entrypoint:`.

Source: [can not mount volume if the directory in container is not empty](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/644)

For the record; you *can* do this when Docker is in Linux mode. Just not in Windows mode.